# How can I put the length of name needs to be bigger than 3 in python?

Tags: python

I want to make sure that the user inputs a name which is more than 3 letters, or else the program will have to repeat the question until the user inputs something which is acceptable.

```
while True:
    if len(name) < 3 
    name = input("What is the student\'s name?")
```

Comment: Can you provide better format?

Comment: I'm afraid `not in(length of 3)` has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: If `if length of x is not bigger than Y then repeat the question` was from an official description for homework, you need to talk to your teacher about needlessly confusing requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
name = ""
while len(name) < 3:
    name = input("What's the student's name?")
    #if python2:
    #name = raw_input("What's the student's name?")
```

**EDIT:**

Worth to remember that in Python2 `input` tries to "guess" input type and if someone will provide for example "23" `input` will parse it to `int` and `len(name)` will throw exception. To avoid it it might be usefull to call `raw_input` instead of `input`.

In Python3 `input` returns string.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: for whom exactly is it "useful"?

Comment: I understand the question as "How to repeat the question until the input is long enough?" This would be the correct answer.

Comment: At least useful to me since it explain to me the difference of input and raw_input. Even experts have the hard time at the beginning of learning. So please be tolerable @thg435.

Comment: @fyr0049: consider reading a python tutorial. Q&A format is not the way to learn a language.

Comment: @thg435. nvm, at least I learnt something, may not be the best way, but it does help

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
x = ""
y = input("Insert Y=")
while len(x) < y:
  x = input("Insert X=")
```